# how to add data to a table in android

Tags: android, mysql, sql, json, tablelayout

I'm trying to populate a table in android app built with xml with data coming in JSON format from MYSQL database, here's the segment of code I tried to populate the table cells:

```
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablelayout1);

        JSONObject jobj = json.getJSONObject(0);

        Log.d("json.getJSONObject(0)", ""+json.getJSONObject(0));
        textView.setId(R.id.tv21);
        textView.setText(jobj.getString("id"));

        Log.d("jobj.getString(c)", ""+jobj.getString("c"));
        rows.addView(textView);
        table.addView(rows);
```

`json.getJSONObject(0)` returns `[{"id":"2222222", "c":"some text"}, "foo":"some other text"}]`

and

`jobj.getString("c")` returns `"some text"`.

I can't set the text at the entry 21 (or in any other entry in the whole table) with the "some text".
Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the individual names of the values. For instance, if your table looked like this (Note, not actually valid(:

```
<TableLayout>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tv1_1/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tv1_2/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tv2_1/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tv2_2/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Then code like this could set it

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablelayout1);
TextView tv=((TextView)table.findViewById(R.id.tv1_1));
tv.setText("Some Text");
```

Depending on your data, you might actually want to use a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html), but I'll save that explanation for another time. It works good with long sets of data, such as the Android contact list.

Comment: Thank you so much @PearsonArtPhoto for your reply! I tried your solution but it didn't work.I was thinking about using ListView and since I'm not dealing with a long sets of data I decided to use TableLayout instead. I tried your approach in two different part of code: inside of onCreate() and doInBackground() methods. On the first one the application crashes throwing NullPointerException but in doBackground() it simply does nothing..

Comment: Try breaking out the TextView command, and see what happened, specifically try and figure out where the null pointer is (The TextView or setting the TextCiew). I'm confident that the code approach will work. I'll show you via an edit. You shouldn't be playing with the UI thread in `doInBackground`. If you have an AsyncTask, you probably want to put the code in `onPostExecute` to set the TextViews.

Comment: I tried your edited solution but It didn't work. A NullPointerException is thrown at tv.setText("Some Text"). So I removed TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablelayout1); and used TextView tv=((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1_1)); and IT WORKED!! Thank you so much again for your help PearsonArtPhoto!